# Необходимость наличия константной ссылки в копирующем конструкторе

Tags: c++

В книге увидел:

> Аргумент конструктора копии должен быть константной ссылкой, чтобы
>   допускать копирование константного объекта.

т.е. если мы передадим неконстантный объект будет ошибкой?

И еще один вопрос, чем отличается копи-конструктор от операции `=` ?

Comment: Вы точно понимаете разницу между аргументом  и параметром?

Comment: @KoVadim к сути дела это отношения не имеет.

Comment: ещё как меняет. агрумент может быть как константный так и нет. А параметр конструктора желательно что бы был константный.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Если вы параметром сделаете неконстантную ссылку, то вы не сможете передать в этот конструктор константный объект. То есть без нужды ограничите свои возможности. Вообще общее правило: если вы передаете по ссылке или указателю некий объект, который не собираетесь модифицировать, передавайте его как константный указатель или ссылку. Тогда вы сможете использовать свой метод или функцию в большем количестве случаев.
2. Конструктор копирования только создает новый объект как копию аргумента, оператор же присваивания по-хорошему должен:

   - корректно удалить старое содержимое;
   - создать новое содержимое как копию переданного аргумента;
   - при этом корректно обработать присвоение самому себе (в конструкторе так не может быть);
   - да еще и вернуть ссылку на свой объект (конструктор ничего не возвращает).

И еще. Когда вы создаете объект следующим образом:

`ClassA a = b;`

то вызывается копирующий конструктор, а не оператор присваивания, как может показаться на первый взгляд.

Comment: Рекомендую для единообразия форматирования использовать готовые нумерованные и ненумерованные списки из редактора.

Comment: @alexolut, учел. Спасибо.

Comment: Я бы во 2-м пункте добавил, что в конструкции `SomeType a; SomeType b = a;` вызывается именно конструктор копирования, а не оператор =.

Comment: Возврат ссылки условие совершенно не обязательное. Но для единообразия (опять таки:) имеет смысл иметь.

Comment: @andi.37, добавил, спасибо.

Comment: @alexolut, да, возвращать ссылку не обязательно. Но я постарался описать хорошую практику.